# How can I select only the first row from each subset of partially distinct values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql database having four columns as given below:

```
  A   B    C   D
1038 496 4789 10 
1303 496 6678 10 
1852 496 1645  8 
 982 496 5203  8
 427 496 5574  8 
  81 496 6908  7 
1264 496 2740  5 
1491 496 6408  4     
1198 496 9766  3
```

As you can see first and second rows have `B` and `D` columns with same values.

I want to select only one row from these two rows having lesser `C` value.

same I want to do with 3rd 4th and 5th row. How to do it?

Comment: Is the current sort critera well-defined? Does your current query have an exact `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select a,b,c,d, row_number() over(partition by b,d order by c) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: will this work with mysql? because I am getting an error.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Comment: @SanjayBhatt, what is y our mysql version

Comment: actually I am solving mysql problems in hackerrank. So the version which they are using.

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL version doesn't support *Windowed Aggregates* you can get the minimum C per B/D and then join back:

```
select *
from tab as t
join 
 (
   select b, d, min(c) as minc
   from tab
   group by b, d
 ) as dt
 on t.b = dt.b
and t.c = dt.minc
and t.d = dt.d
```